# Replace value in column based on multiple conditions in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(
    {
        'Name': ['Jane', 'Melissa', 'John', 'Matt'],
        'Age': [23, 45, 35, 64],
        'Birth City': ['London', 'Paris', 'Toronto', 'Atlanta'],
        'Gender': ['F', 'F', 'M', 'M']
    }
)
```

and I want to replace the `Gender` to `X`, when the name is `Melissa` or `John`. How would I do this?

Comment: Both answers are good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
df['Gender'] = df['Gender'].mask(df['Name'].isin(['Melissa', 'John']), other='X')
```

Output:

```
      Name  Age Birth City Gender
0     Jane   23     London      F
1  Melissa   45      Paris      X
2     John   35    Toronto      X
3     Matt   64    Atlanta      M
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is my solution:

```
df.loc[((df['Name'] == 'Melissa') | (df['Name'] == 'John')), 'Gender'] = 'X'
```

And output

```
      Name  Age Birth City Gender
0     Jane   23     London      F
1  Melissa   45      Paris      X
2     John   35    Toronto      X
3     Matt   64    Atlanta      M
```